# jquery mobile login page on seperate HTML

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm making a hybrid app with JQM v1.4.

The first page is login page and the user must login first to see content pages.

So I will seperate html page like...
1 login page it self, and other content page will put all together in single html page.

login.html / content.html

my login page source is

```
<form action="content.html" method="post" data-ajax="false">
    <label for="login_username">Username:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="login_username" id="login_username" /><br>
    <label for="login_password">Password:</label><br>
    <input type="password" name="login_password" id="login_password" /><br>
    <button id="login_submit" type="submit" data-theme="a">Submit</button>
</form>
```

When click the submit button, page will be change to content.html

Before I give my source to App Developer, is this valid Code? I mean, it works, just wondering if there was a better way.

please Help~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try set your javascript using this code

```
formData = {
    login_username: $("#login_username"),
    login_password: $("#login_password")

}
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: "http://localhost/register.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: formData,
    success: function(data) {
        window.location.replace("content.html");
    },
    error: function(data) {
        //error handler
    }
});
```

You setup your login logic using this reference.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

I hope it help you.